# How to identify if a TBytes array may safely convert to AnsiString, string or UTF8String?

Tags: delphi

Given a TBytes array, can we identify if the array may convert to AnsiString, String or UTF8String without losing any characters?

Comment: Converted how? How is the byte array encoded?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Unable to determine.  It is either using ANSI, UTF8 or Unicode.

Comment: If you don't know how it's encoded then you can't do anything with any certainty. How can you know whether or not the conversion succeeded if you don't know what the bytes represent?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I may use `LocaleCharsFromUnicode()` to test if a string is Ansi or Unicode and use matched encoding to convert the string to TBytes array.  But It seems no easy way to convert TBytes array back to matched string.

Comment: Answer is `always yes` for 8-bit characters because **bytes are not encoded** at all. You have to know more about content. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318672

Comment: Why do you have an array of bytes whose encoding you don't know?

Comment: @FreeConsulting: Using `IsTextUnicode(B, Length(B), nil)` works like a charm where B is TBytes array.

Comment: A conversion needs a source encoding and a destination encoding. So it should first be established what the source encoding is. If the wrong conversion is done, it is possible that the source can't be entirely and safely encoded to the destination.

Comment: @ChauCheeYang, you should supply `lpiResult` tests set and check result on return because you already ruled out byte-reversed encodings as per your question. Also, my preceding comment stands, you cannot tell if your non-Unicode bytes are text or not w/o statistical analysis.

Answer (score 1):

What you appear to be asking to do is impossible. You seem to have a byte array of unknown provenance, that may be encoded as ANSI, UTF-8 or UTF-16. You are hoping to be able to determine which encoding is correct.

This is impossible because there exist byte arrays that are valid in all three of those encodings, and that represent different strings in each encoding. Raymond Chen shows a nice clean example here: [The Notepad file encoding problem, redux](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx).

You can use heuristic algorithms to attempt to guess the encoding, an example of which is `IsTextUnicode`. But any such approach is by necessity not robust.

Comment: Not even IsTextUnicode can perform that which is impossible